# mysql query ignores where clause when query for wrong data type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has a STATUS TINYINT(1) column and DEFAULT 0. All the records now have 0 for this column. When I query this with where status = 'active', the results seem to ignore this clause and return all the results. Is this the default behavior of SQL or MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is that MySQL is doing silent conversion.  When a string is used in a numeric context, it is converted to a number, based on the leading digits.

There are no leading digits in `'active'`.  So, the value is converted to 0.  Hence, your logic become (after the conversion):

```
status = 0
```

Pay attention to types and to the constants used for comparison.

Comment: Is there a way to have MySQL not do this? like give out an error?

Comment: I don't think so (although I am not 100% sure).  There is an option to prevent the conversion when loading data into tables.